# How can I run this JavaScript snake game in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I have this Snake game written in JavaScript and when I go to run the game.js file by clicking the run icon on the top right part of the screen I get this error.

```
[Running] node "/Users/matthewrowlinson/Documents/Javascript Code/snake/game.js"
(node:79394) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/matthewrowlinson/Documents/Javascript Code/snake/game.js:1
import { update as updateSnake, draw as drawSnake, SNAKE_SPEED, getSnakeHead, snakeIntersection } from './snake.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.065 seconds
```

Which is funny because I shouldn't get this error because I specifically set the type="module" in the html file.

```
<script src="game.js" defer type="module"></script>
```

So far this is the only way I have seen as an answer for this error, setting the type to "module" and I don't know why it does nothing and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: You're running the code in Node, not in a browser. Run it in a browser instead.

Comment: If you _do_ want to write this for node, the easiest is to change the extension of the file to `.mjs`

Answer (score -1):

I'll have to assume that you are trying to host a node script, and the "game.js" script is included in the html file via `<script src="game.js" defer type="module"></script>`.

the "import" option only works on the server side node script.
I'm assuming that when you connect to the server, you want game.js and the html file to pop up on your browser. This means that the game.js will be running on the client side, where you can't have "node modules" or "imports".

To include a js script in html, you don't need to specify "defer type" or any of the module stuff.

TL:DR

you can just do `<script src="game.js"`>

OR

if you don't need to host a server,
do `<script src="game.js"></script>`

I can't make a really good judgement because I need to assume a lot of things. Is there any more information?

Comment: So I need to run the program with node?

Comment: do you want to just open it in the browser, or host it on an ip (or website address (domain) if you have one) so that everyone can play on it?